# How do I change the interval time in System.Threading.Timer from the callback function of this timer?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, timertask

How do I change the interval in System.Threading.Timer from the callback function of this timer?
Is this correct?

Doing so. Did not happen.

```
public class TestTimer
{
    private static Timer _timer = new Timer(TimerCallBack); 

    public void Run()
    {
        _timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    private static void TimerCallBack(object obj)
    {
        if(true)
            _timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, that is valid for some good reason, testing for example ?

Comment: Mitch, it's just an example. Do not take it to heart. lol

Comment: plus 1 just because you need it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line generate infinite recursion:

```
if(true)
    _timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

The first parameter forces `TimerCallBack` to execute right away. So it executes it again and again indefinitely.

The fix would be

```
if(true)
    _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your call to `Change` specifies that the *next* call should happen *immediately*. If you're going to call `Change` *every* time, you can just use a period of [`Timeout.Infinite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite) (which is just a constant of -1) to tell it to avoid repeating at all after the next time - but it will still keep firing, because that next time, you reset it. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

static class Program
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallBack); 

    public static void Main()
    {
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }

    private static void TimerCallBack(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Fired", DateTime.Now);
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                     TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change it just once, and then leave it:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

static class Program
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallBack); 
    private static bool changed = false;

    public static void Main()
    {
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }

    private static void TimerCallBack(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Fired", DateTime.Now);
        if (!changed)
        {
            changed = true;
            TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            timer.Change(interval, interval);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that nothing is using the initial interval (1 second in the samples above) in either case, because we're calling `Change` immediately - if you really want a different time before the first call, don't use `TimeSpan.Zero` in the initial call to `Change`.

Comment: Just for the record, while you can of course use -1 for "Infinite", the docs do say you can use `Timeout.Infinite`, which I think more clearly shows the intention. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins: True Will edit. (Although if `Timeout.Infinite` were a `TimeSpan` it would be clearer - the docs for `Timer.Change(int,int)` mention `Timeout.Infinite`; the docs for `Timer.Change(TimeSpan, TimeSpaan)` don't :(

Comment: Yeah, got to love the consistency there, lol. ;) Not surprised at all really, come to expect this, along with other useless doc info.

Comment: For infinite value in`Timer.Change(TimeSpan, TimeSpan)` the `Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan` field can be used.