# .net core WebService TimeHostedService change Timer-Interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, timer

In my .net core 3.1 application I'm using a `IHostedService` for executing a timed background-task.

My class looks like:

```
internal class TimeHostedStorageService : IHostedService
{
    private Timer timer;
    private TimeSpan queryTimeSpan;

    
    public TimeHostedStorageService()
    {
        queryTimeSpan = ReadNewTimeSpanFromConfigFile();
    }
        
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // Initial the queryTimeSpan is at 5 Minutes
        timer = new Time(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, queryTimeSpan);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        // Do some background-actions here
        // Read from DB/Logging/...
                
        
        // now I want to check if the TimeSpan for the timer should be changed and change it:
        TimeSpan newTimeSpan = ReadNewTimeSpanFromConfigFile();     
        if(newTimeSpan != queryTimeSpan)
        {           
            timer?.Change(ZimeSpan.Zero, newTimeSpan);
        }
        
    }
    
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Initial the `TimeSpan` for the Timer is 5 Minutes. As long as I don't change the value for the `TimeSpan` in my config-file everything just works fine.

At the moment I change the `TimeSpan` (to let's say 10 Minutes) the DoWork-Method is called several times parallel and every second it seems.

I think the problem is within the `timer?.Change(ZimeSpan.Zero, newTimeSpan);`. But I don't see another way to change the interval for the Timer while runtime...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Time.Change() function in the DoWork method like below:

```
if (newTimeSpan != queryTimeSpan)
{
    timer?.Change(newTimeSpan, newTimeSpan);
}
```

Otherwise, the first parameter will force `DoWork` to execute right away. So it executes it again and again indefinitely.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119932/11965297) is a similiar question. You can refer to it.